# Javascript - p5.FFT not working with p5-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, p5.js

I tried taking my project from p5.js editor to a react app, I changed my code into this documentation format: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-p5.

I added "p5/lib/addons/p5.sound.js" (FFT is in there) to App.js but it still giving me this error:

"Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): p5.FFT is not a constructor"

The code in the p5 website is:

```js
let fft_bins = 64;
function setup() {
    let cnv = createCanvas(screen_size[0], screen_size[1]);
    fft = new p5.FFT(0.9, fft_bins);
}
```

The code in my react app is:

```js
import "p5/lib/addons/p5.sound.js"

let fft_bins = 64;
const setup = (p5, canvasParentRef) => {
    let cnv = p5.createCanvas(screen_size[0], screen_size[1]).parent(canvasParentRef);
    fft = new p5.FFT(0.9, fft_bins);
};
```

Comment: Can you post your actual code? (both the normal p5, and the react p5 version)

Comment: @Samathingamajig updated, thank you.

Comment: [p5.sound isn't supported by react-p5 natively](https://github.com/Gherciu/react-p5/issues/27), how are you importing it?

Comment: @Samathingamajig I added in the top of the code: import "p5/lib/addons/p5.sound.js", do you recommend about a different library for that? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are trying to access a type constructor on the p5 **instance** that `react-p5` passes to the setup function instead of accessing it via the static `p5` object (which happens to be the constructor for a `p5` instance). There are two ways to access this 1) because `react-p5` conveniently initializes `window.p5` you can access it globally, you just need to change the name of the argument in your setup function declaration since you are currently shadowing the variable name, or 2) you can use `Object.getPrototypeOf(p).constructor.FFT` where `p` is the first parameter passed to the setup function:

```
const setup = (p5, canvasParentRef) => {
    let cnv = p5.createCanvas(screen_size[0], screen_size[1]).parent(canvasParentRef);
    fft = new Object.getPrototypeOf(p).constructor.FFT(0.9, fft_bins);
};
```

Here's a simple example using `Oscillator` instead of `FFT`:

```js
// // In a project consisting of multiple modules compiled with webpack
// // or browserify would use import statements:
// import React from 'react';
// import Sketch from 'react-p5';
const Sketch = reactP5;

function Example(props) {
  let osc, playing;

  const setup = (p, canvasParentRef) => {
    // use parent to render the canvas in this ref
    // (without that p5 will render the canvas outside of your component)
    p.createCanvas(300, 300).parent(canvasParentRef);
    osc = new p5.Oscillator('sine');
    
    // This would not work:
    // console.log(new p.Vector(1, 2, 3));
    // But this does:
    const Vector = Object.getPrototypeOf(p).constructor.Vector;
    console.log(new Vector(1, 2, 3));
  };

  const draw = (p) => {
    p.background(0);
    p.fill(props.color || 'blue');
    p.ellipse(
      p.width / 2 + 100 * p.sin(p.frameCount / 100 * p.PI),
      p.height / 2 - 100 * p.cos(p.frameCount / 100 * p.PI),
      70,
      70
    );


    let freq = p.map(p.sin(p.frameCount / 200 * p.PI), -1, 1, 100, 500);
    osc.freq(freq, 0.1);
    if (playing) {
      let amp = p.map(p.cos(p.frameCount / 100 * p.PI), -1, 1, 0.1, 0.3);
      // smooth the transitions by 0.1 seconds
      osc.amp(amp, 0.1);
    }
  };

  const mousePressed = (p) => {
    osc.start();
    playing = true;
  };

  const mouseReleased = (p) => {
    osc.amp(0, 0.5);
    playing = false;
  };

  return <Sketch setup={setup} draw={draw} mousePressed={mousePressed} mouseReleased={mouseReleased} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Example />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
  <!-- react-p5 bundles p5.js v1.1.9 and sets window.p5 -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-p5@1.3.19/build/index.min.js"></script>
  <!-- we need to manually include p5.sound -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.1.9/lib/addons/p5.sound.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Note: when serving or building a React app with react-scripts it may be necessary to use `window.p5` or `global.p5` instead of just `p5` when doing things like `new p5.Oscillator('sine');`. This is because `react-p5` exports `p5` globally but webpack is not aware of that.